# How i can navigate from View Controller to another View Controller once clicking on button?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uibutton

I am getting this exception when I am trying to move to another view:

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle  (loaded)' with name 'NextViewController''

```
NextViewController *temp = [[NextViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"NextViewController" bundle:nil];
[self presentViewController:temp animated:YES comletion:nil];
```

Comment: Do you have the file NextViewController.xib in your project ?

Comment: put self.navigationController in the place of self.

Comment: are you adding the navigation controller?

Comment: I used storyboard not xib. Also, I'm working on log-in screen, so i don't need navigationcontroller because i don't need any user to go back for a log-in screen after log-in successfully. –

Answer (score 1):

Exception says that you don't have the **NextViewController.xib** file in your project. Double check whether you have it or not.

Also make sure you have given the **NextViewController** as your **File's Owner Class** of **NextViewController.xib**

[image]

Comment: I'm used storyboard not xib. Also, I'm working on log-in screen, so i don't need Navigation Controller because i don't need any user to go back for a log-in screen after log-in successfully.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, check if you really have **NextViewController.xib**?
If No, then how can you load your nib file?
Also, check if you have NextViewController given as **File's Owner class**?

If yes,

Check, if you used have **navigationcontroller**?
If yes, then change your code to :

```
NextViewController *temp = [[NextViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"NextViewController" bundle:nil];
[self.navigationcontroller presentViewController:temp animated:YES comletion:nil];
```

Comment: Why i need another .xib ? Firstly, i used storyboard not xib.
Also, I'm working on log-in screen, so i don't need navigationcontroller because i don't need any user to go back for a log-in screen after log-in successfully.

Comment: Where in your question did you mention that you have used storyboard? or that you have not used navigation controller? Be specific in your question to get correct answers. And refer to storyboard developer docs before posting the question.

Comment: Sorry for that, i'm new on iOS and this is a first question i posted on stackoverflow..

Comment: No problem. Just remember it next time onwards :)

Answer (score 0):

First you create uinavigationcontroller object first view set as a rootview controller after that set button on rootviewcontroller and push nextvie.

```
//for mainviewcontroller
UINavigationController *navigation =[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:viewcontroller];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:nextview animated:YES];
```

Comment: I'm used storyboard not xib. Also, I'm working on log-in screen, so i don't need Navigation Controller because i don't need any user to go back for a log-in screen after log-in successfully.

Answer (score 0):

make sure you have the nib named `NextViewController` on your project. and also check if its added on your bundle resources. see screenshot [image]

Comment: I'm used storyboard not xib. Also, I'm working on log-in screen, so i don't need Navigation Controller because i don't need any user to go back for a log-in screen after log-in successfully.

Comment: maybe you should have stated that you are using storyboard  not xib on your post

Answer (score 0):

If you are using swift 3.0,try below code

```
//Here you can initiate your new ViewController
    let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)

    let nextViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "VadiveluPageViewController") as! VadiveluPageViewController
    self.present(nextViewController, animated:true, completion:nil)

    //if you need navigation controller use below
//self.navigationController?.pushViewController(nextViewController, animated: true)
```

Answer (score 0):

Create 2 view controller in main story borad.
Go to main story board and select one view controller in main story board and drag and put into another view controller and select show method.

Make sure to create class and identifer name in second View Controller.

Go to Editor option and select navigation method. And put the below code in button action function.

```
self.performSegue(withIdentifer: "IdentiferName", sender: self)
```